Unable to configure opentelemetry to service
I have a service that is configured with 3.2.x spring boot, i want to configure opentelemetry for the service and added io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel and io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-otlp to pom(maven dependencies) as suggested by spring boot document(https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.micrometer-tracing). Are otel beans autoconfigured here? spring doc says Use the management.otlp.tracing. configuration properties to configure reporting using OTLP.* what does it mean? Should i create a bean for properties or can i add properties under application.properties/environment variables?
Firstly i have tried sleuth autoconfigure dependencies it did not work as spring version is 3.2.x. So i have followed above approach still unable to see traces in collector after adding dependencies. Want to know if i need to configure a bean or add properties in .props files.
